# Node js Express module.js:340

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having trouble running my app in node. When I first got the `module.js:340` error, I used a `sudo npm install express -g`, and it looked like Express is installed but when I run my app again I get this error.

```
   module.js:340
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'express'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/Downloads/node-FED-master/app.js:6:15)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    users-Mac-Pro:node-FED-master mac$
```

Answer (score 1):

You've installed Express globally (with `-g`), which gives you access to the `express` command line tool, but Node programs can't access the global module.  You need to install Express locally by doing `npm install express` in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the project has a `package.json`, a simple `npm install` in the project directory will install all necessary dependencies in it's correct versions.